# Load intro page before index

Tags: flash

I would like to load an index.html file for 3 seconds just before my usual index.asp file.
How can I do it?

THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you server is configured to prioritise the loading of index.html, you could use JavaScript to load a subsequent page after a given time interval.

You don’t *really* want to do this though do you? It’s very bad form. The JavaScript redirect would leave behind any search engine crawlers and other robots.

Comment: Thank you, it is just to put an important announce for some days, so I really need to do this. So something like this should work? http://www.quackit.com/javascript/codes/timed_javascript_redirect.cfm

Comment: That would do the trick. An alternative would be to show your announcement in a modal window - i.e. a div that overlays the page, and visitors can click a close widget to dismiss it.